# SecurityException: Permission Denial. opening provider xxx from xxx that is not exported from uid 10027

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a project A as library jar file, which contains a  ContentProvider. Then I need to use it in project B. As declared in Manifest:

```
        <provider
        android:authorities="com.gezbox.android.onepiece"
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="com.gezbox.android.api.provider.GezboxProvider"/>
```

But problem comes then:

```
 04-17 17:55:50.695: WARN/dalvikvm(5527): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40def300)
04-17 17:55:50.695: WARN/ActivityManager(258): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10027
04-17 17:55:50.695: WARN/ActivityManager(258): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10027
04-17 17:55:50.695: WARN/ActivityManager(258): Permission Denial: opening provider com.gezbox.android.api.provider.GezboxProvider from ProcessRecord{415d5e08 5527:com.gezbox.android.onepiece/u0a31} (pid=5527, uid=10031) that is not exported from uid 10027
04-17 17:55:50.711: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5527): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GezboxService]
        java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.gezbox.android.api.provider.GezboxProvider from ProcessRecord{415d5e08 5527:com.gezbox.android.onepiece/u0a31} (pid=5527, uid=10031) that is not exported from uid 10027

        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2354)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4219)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContextImpl.java:1688)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:1083)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(ContentResolver.java:1146)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:896)
        at com.gezbox.android.api.processor.PostOrderProcessor.updateContentProvider(PostOrderProcessor.java:57)
        at com.gezbox.android.api.processor.PostOrderProcessor.post_order(PostOrderProcessor.java:33)
        at com.gezbox.android.api.GezboxService.onHandleIntent(GezboxService.java:196)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem solved. I changed the provider's uri for Providers in project B.

Yes I was so dump...

The library projects were wrote by another guy, each time before I compile the project I need to change the uri manually so that it fits the right path.

Comment: Hi! Can you please explain what you exactly did with xml? I am also facing this problem.

Comment: Yes please, why does the URI change each time? That doesn't sound right.